# Jekyll command bundle exec jekyll serve automatically loads site made previously

Tags: jekyll

I am working with Jekyll on a new project.  I created a new project by running jekyll new [folder name] then ran bundle exec jekyll serve.  However every time I run that command files from a former jekyll project get put in the folder!  I am not using this project anymore (more of me learning jekyll on my own) so I even deleted the folders.  Still, this old site files get loaded.

I even tried serving the site over a different port number (4001, not 4000), and uninstalling and reinstalling the jekyll gem.  What is going wrong?   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved.

I ended up creating a blank default index file in the root.  When I did this and ran jekyll serve, the index file of the former site ceased to be generated.  Still generated another page from the site, but I am assuming I can prevent that the same way.